# Problems with reading pickle files from Azure Blob Storage into Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks, pickle, azure-databricks

I have a pickle file saved in Azure Blob Storage, that I want to load into Azure Databricks. I have tried several methods, and they all give me the same error message, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named Types". I have mounted the Blob container with name "test2", and try to load the pickle file with:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pickle

os.chdir(r'/dbfs/mnt/test2/')

with open('EEDict.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
    EEDict = pd.read_pickle(handle)
```

However, it does not seem like there are any modules named "Types", or at least I am not able to import it. Therefore, I suspect that the problem might be something else.

I am able to read a csv file from the same Blob Container, so the problem is only with the pickle file. In other words, this code does read the csv file "test_blob.csv" as expected.

```py
with open('test_blob.csv', 'rb') as handle:
    test = pd.read_csv(handle)
```

Comment: Could you share the code in text instead of sharing it as a screenshot?

Comment: you need to have all dependencies installed on your cluster - it looks like something is missing, like, your custom libraries

Comment: You are totally right, Alex! I just figured out myself that "Types" was a custom folder in my original Python project. I don't know the project very well yet, therefore I was confused. Thank you.

Comment: @AstridMeg post the solution as answer so that it will help community with same type issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's the standard Python problem that araise when you read pickle file and don't have all necessary dependencies installed on the cluster.

From Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled):

> *Note that functions (built-in and user-defined) are pickled by fully qualified name, not by value. This means that only the function name is pickled, along with the name of the containing module and classes. Neither the function’s code, nor any of its function attributes are pickled.* **Thus the defining module must be importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain the named object, otherwise an exception will be raised.**

Solution is to make sure that all necessary packages are installed.